# How to add spaces to the end of value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to return values of a certain length. My goal is to add spaces at the end if it doesn't reach the length that I'm looking for.

Here is what I'm doing to try and achieve this goal:

```
LEFT(CAST(i.A_BILLED AS NVARCHAR)+REPLICATE(' ',12),12)
```

A_BILLED is of type "decimal(20, 6)". For some reason, this semi-works on values of this type, although instead of adding spaces like I would expect, it's adding 0's. How can I make it so it adds spaces instead?

Comment: If you need fixed width, why not use a `(n)char` instead?

Comment: It's not adding zeroes; that's what your `CAST` is doing, and it's doing that because of your `DECIMAL`'s (fixed) precision. Note that using `NVARCHAR` without a length is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), although it's not causing trouble here.

Comment: `'decimal` is a numeric type. Nothing inherent in its use involves spaces.

Comment: I must ask, however, why do you want to return a numerical value as a strong based data type, and *not* a numerical value

Comment: @Larnu I believe I did that so I could add spaces to meet the length I was looking for.

Comment: That isn't what I'm asking, @BlakeB9 . I'm not asking why you cast it to an `nvarchar`, I'm asking why you want a string based data type.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I mean I don't need it to be. The only reason why I was doing so was to add spaces. But yeah, doing nchar(12) to make it of length 12 does the trick... I made it so complicated

Comment: @wqw [`LEN()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql) maybe doesn't work the way you think it does, i.e.: _Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, excluding trailing spaces._ For comparison take a look at `SELECT DATALENGTH('aaa'), DATALENGTH('aaa   ');`

Comment: You could also try `LEFT(CONCAT (A_BILLED, REPLICATE (' ', 12)), 12)`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes, you are right. It was the equality comparison on VARCHAR columns which was trimming trailing spaces which is out of the ordinary. https://pastebin.com/bLBrCYzX